# In keras, is doing fit() over many single datepoints the same as doing fit() over a dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

In keras, is doing fit() over many single datepoints the same as doing fit() over a dataset? For example, is doing a single

```
model.fit(train_X,
          train_y,
          batch_size=1,
          epochs=1)
```

The same as doing

```
for i in range(len(train_X)):
    model.fit([train_X[i]],
              [train_y[i]],
              batch_size=1,
              epochs=1)
```

Or is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `model.fit()` for a whole dataset will shuffle the samples each epoch, which can help with the learning process. If you do it the looped-way, you it will be updating the weights to the same progression of samples.

`model.fit` will update the weights after every batch, in your case after every sample. So aside of the shuffling, the two methods you proposed are the same.